# Javascript not working with ie browser and ff

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have a javascript that redirects the news and events height to the heighest so that they all have the same height size, somehow it's not working in mozilla and ie.

However with chrome it works fully making them all the same size. Neither of the other browsers display any errors in the console so im having a hard time to debug it

This is my only part of my index page including the div im using and the script in js , im using laravel as framework btw :

```
<div class="col-md-8 news homepage s2">
     <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
               @foreach($events as $n)
                   <div class="swiper-slide remove_p">
                        <h4>{!! nl2br($n['titulo_'.$lang]) !!}</h4>
                        {!! nl2br($n['desc_'.$lang]) !!}
                        <a href="{{ ROUTE('page', ['cat' => 'eventos', 'id' => $n->id]) }}" class="link more_btn">{{ $geral['SAIBA_MAIS']->value }}</a>
                   </div>
               @endforeach
          </div>              
     </div>
     <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>

@section('scripts')
@parent

<script type="text/javascript">
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.homepage.s1 .swiper-container', {
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.homepage.s1 .swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.homepage.s1 .swiper-button-prev',
    },
    breakpoints: {
      480: {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 100
      }
    }
});

var mySwiper = new Swiper('.homepage.s2 .swiper-container', {
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.homepage.s2 .swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.homepage.s2 .swiper-button-prev',
    },
    breakpoints: {
      480: {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 100
      }
    }
});
</script>
<script>
  setTimeout(resizeSwiper, 500)
  setTimeout(resizeSwiper, 1000)
  setTimeout(resizeSwiper, 2000)
  setTimeout(resizeSwiper, 3000)

  function resizeSwiper() {
    $('.swiper-container').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this)
      var height = 0
      $this.find('.swiper-slide').each(function() {
        var s_title_h = $(this).find('h4').height()
        var s_p_h = $(this).find('p').eq(0).height()

        if(height < (s_title_h + s_p_h)) {
          height = (s_title_h + s_p_h)
        }
      })

      $this.css({
        'height': height + 50
      })

      $(this).parent().parent().find('.col-md-4.line_block').css({
        'height': height + 50
      })

      $(this).parent().parent().find('.col-md-4.img_eventos').css({
        'height': height + 50
      })

    })

    /*$('.img_eventos').css({
      'height': $('.swiper-container').eq(1).height() + 0
    })*/
  }
</script>
@endsection
```

The same is also for the slider, its not showing in both browsers

Comment: Since you are using laravel, why don't you tag this post as laravel?

Comment: Going to be hard to help with all the code and not having it running... Only thing I can suggest is to add some console.log() lines and figure out what is not working exactly right.

Comment: Provide an MCVE.  Reduce the code to the HTML and Javascript that can reproduce the problem so people can assist you.  Add it to a fiddle for bonus points.

Comment: Regarding to javascript is all the code that is down, i only included that, not all the page code

Comment: I removed useless parts can you check it now? @epascarello

Comment: I removed useless parts can you check it now? @Devon